# Server-side vs. Client side computations

Tags: d3.js, client-side, networkx

So I'm trying to implement a project where I have graph data (few 100 nodes for now, but could become a million later) stored as a json file.

- I'm using **NetworkX** libraries in python to generate all the data
  from some information, and then sending over the json file to the
  client side.
- I'm using **d3.js** to represent the graph in javascript
  on the client side.

Now, on the user's request, I need to delete the shortest path between two nodes of the user's choice in my graph and show them the resulting graph.
I know that this processing has to be done on the client-side to prevent excess server load, but this is what I'm unsure about:

- An optimized graph library is what does this the fastest. In fact, NetworkX probably has a ready-made function for this. But it's in python. Is writing a shortest path deletion function in javascript the intelligent thing to do?
- Does d3.js have these sort of functions? Or is it a library only for representing stuff graphically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 doesn't have functions for this. It sounds like in your case the best way to go would be to implement this functionality in Javascript yourself (or find a library that does it). If you need more sophisticated functionality however, relying on something like NetworkX is almost certainly going to be easier and faster to implement though.